# Wordpress - How do I display post content html in my page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress I am trying to display the first 10 posts in the database with a shortcode with this code. It's just an experiment to learn.

```
function do_hello_world()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts LIMIT 10');

    $content = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        $content = $content . $result[$i];
    }

    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('hello_world', 'do_hello_world');
```

But I get the following error on my page when the shortcode is added.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   D:\Work\DGS\Cam_Rent\Site\wp-includes\shortcodes.php on line 325 Array

I checked in the database and post_content is a long text filled with HTML. Shouldn't this code make a string? My goal is to display the HTML from those posts on my page, how would I do that?

Comment: Its better to use WP_Query for shortcode. Here is the link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: _“and post_content is a long text filled with HTML”_ - but you are not _accessing_ the post content here - `$result[$i]` is an array that contains multiple properties. Use `var_dump` to check what a variable actually contains, in cases where you are not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said **Mohammad Ashique Ali**, it's better to not use directly wpdb, there is a lot of wordpress functions like `wp_posts` :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

try this :

```
add_shortcode("hello_world", function ($attr, $content, $tag) {


    $posts = get_posts([
        "post_type" => "post",
        "posts_per_page" => 10,
    ]);


    $result = "";

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        $result .= $post->post_content . "<hr/>";

    }


    return $result;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Insert PHP Code Snippet** plugin.

1. Install the plugin.
2. Then you got a sidebar menu like XYZ PHP Code.
3. Add a new snippet and write your code.
4. Insert this snippet to your page post and publish it.

Plugin link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/

Answer (score 0):

> I checked in the database and post_content is a long text filled with
>   HTML. Shouldn't this code make a string?

No.

If you use the [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function to see what the value of `$result` is, you'll get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_content] => <!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
        )

    ...

)
```

An array of *objects*.

The reason why you're getting that PHP warning is because you're trying to concatenate a string (`$content`) with an object (`$result[$i]`, which is a `stdClass Object`):

```
$content = $content . $result[$i];
```

To access the actual content from your posts (and fix the problem), change that line to:

```
$content = $content . $result[$i]->post_html;
```

Notice how now we're using the `post_html` property of the object to retrieve the HTML of the post.